# Fatoração em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como fatorar numeros nessa forma ?

```
26 | 2
13 | 3
1  |
```

Segue meu código ainda incompleto:
**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gu7cy22L/2/)**

Comment: Você quer os fatores primos ou outro tipo de fatoração?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seguindo a lógica da fatoração cheguei a esta função:

```
function Calcular(nr) {
    var partes = [];
    while (nr > 1) {
        for (var i = 2; i <= nr; i++) {
            if (nr % i) continue;
            partes.push([nr, i]);
            nr = nr / i;
            break;
        }
    }
    partes.push([1, '']);
    return partes;
}
```

Alguns exemplos seriam:

```
Calcular(4); // "[[4,2],[2,2],[1,""]]" 
Calcular(3); // "[[3,3],[1,""]]" 
Calcular(5); // "[[5,5],[1,""]]"
Calcular(6); // "[[6,2],[3,3],[1,""]]"
Calcular(8); // "[[8,2],[4,2],[2,2],[1,""]]"
```

Depois montar o HTML depende de como quer o formato final. Supondo que usamos a mesma tabela aqui fica uma sugestão:

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLmxnm0q/

Answer (score 4):

NOTA: Eu não sei se você pôs seu exemplo errado, já que `13` não e
divisível por `3` ou se é aquilo mesmo que você quer que seja
exibido. Se for comente que eu atualizo minha resposta.

Vou escrever em `C`, já que não sei JS, mas deve ser bem parecido e,
mais importante, mais simples do que o código que você postou.

A primeira coisa é que você vai precisar de uma lista de números primos para fazer a fatoração. Se você não tiver a lista já em mãos, você pode usar um algoritmo para gerar essa lista pra você. Um jeito clássico, no sentido literal da palavra, [já que foi
"inventado" por Erastosthenes uns 2000 anos atras](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crivo_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes), é o seguinte:

1. Estabelecemos um numero limite para encontrarmos primos ate ele (`N`).
2. Declaramos uma lista `L` contendo `N` valores `true`. Essa
      lista, ao final do algoritmo, vai obedecer à seguinte relação:

   - Se `L[i] == true`, se e somente se `i` é um numero primo.
3. Agora, procedemos da seguinte maneira:

   - Marcamos `L[0]` e `L[1]` como `false`, já que ambos `0` e
     `1` não são primos.
   - A partir do `i = 2`, se  `i` for primo (`L[i] == true`), 
     marcamos todos os seus múltiplos como não primos. Isto é, fazemos `L[2*i] = false`, `L[3*i] = false`, etc.

Isso, em `C`, pode ficar assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N 1000 /* Nosso limite */

bool L[N + 1];

void peneira() {
    /* Primeiro marcamos todos como true */
    memset(L, true, sizeof(L));

    /* Agora o 0 e o 1 não são primos */
    L[0] = L[1] = false;

    /* A parte mágica */
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; ++i) {
        if (L[i]) {
            /* Se i é um numero primo, seus múltiplos não são */
            for(int k = i + i; k <= N; k += i){
                L[k] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    peneira();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        if (L[i]) {
            printf("%d e primo\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Rodando isso, a saída e:

```
2 e primo
3 e primo
5 e primo
7 e primo
11 e primo
13 e primo
17 e primo
19 e primo
23 e primo
29 e primo
```

Ou seja, todos os primos ate `30`.

Agora que temos todos os primos ate nosso limite `N`, podemos fatorar
qualquer numero:

```
void fatora(int num) {
    /* Vou calcular o numero de digitos de num para imprimirmos
     * bonitinho como no seu exemplo */
     int tamanho = floor(log10(num)) + 1;
     int primo = 2;
     while (num > 1) {
         /* Enqto num e divisivel por primo */
         while (num % primo == 0) {
             printf("%*d | %d\n", tamanho, num, primo);
             num /= primo;
         }
         /* Agora vamos para o proximo primo */
         ++primo;
         while (L[primo] == false) {
             ++primo;
         }
     }
     /* Imprimimos a ultima linha */
     printf("%*d | \n", tamanho, 1);
}
```

Finalmente, se rodarmos

```
int main() {
    peneira();
    fatora(26);
    return 0;
}
```

A saída vai ser:

```
26 | 2
13 | 13
1  |
```

Answer (score 1):

Achei na internet. Não testei, mas parece funcionar:

```
function fator(numero) {
   if (isNaN(numero) || !isFinite(numero) || numero%1!=0 || numero==0) return ''+numero;
   if (numero<0) return '-'+fator(-numero);
   var minFator = lFator(numero);
   if (numero==minFator) return ''+numero;
   return minFator+'*'+fator(numero/minFator);
}

function lFator(numero) {
   if (isNaN(numero) || !isFinite(numero)) return NaN;  
   if (numero==0) return 0;  
   if (numero%1 || numero*numero<2) return 1;
   if (numero%2==0) return 2;  
   if (numero%3==0) return 3;  
   if (numero%5==0) return 5;  
   var m = Math.sqrt(numero);
   for (var i=7;i<=m;i+=30) {
      if (numero%i==0)      return i;
      if (numero%(i+4)==0)  return i+4;
      if (numero%(i+6)==0)  return i+6;
      if (numero%(i+10)==0) return i+10;
      if (numero%(i+12)==0) return i+12;
      if (numero%(i+16)==0) return i+16;
      if (numero%(i+22)==0) return i+22;
      if (numero%(i+24)==0) return i+24;
   }
   return numero;
}
```

Fonte: [Javascriper](http://www.javascripter.net/math/primes/factorization.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
function fatoracao(aNumIn) {
var aRetorno = [
    [1, 1]
];
pFator = 1;
while (aNumIn != 1) {
    pFator++;
    pVezes = 0;
    while (aNumIn % pFator == 0) {
        pVezes += 1;
        aNumIn /= pFator;
    }
    if (pVezes) aRetorno.push([pFator, pVezes]);
}
return aRetorno;
}
let aIn = Math.pow(2, 5) * Math.pow(3, 2) * Math.pow(11, 1) * Math.pow(17, 2) * Math.pow(29, 1);
console.log(aIn, " >>>>  ", fatoracao(aIn));
// 26551008 ' >>>>  ' [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 11, 1 ], [ 17, 2 ], [ 29, 1 ] ]
```

Bem, o código acima retorna um vetor fatorado. Agora você poderá formatar a saída como desejar...